# How to fix '500 error in jquery when loading content from another page'?

Tags: jquery, django-templates

So, I am using javascript to load details in the list page and it works but the problem is coming out of it again. So I did the same but triggering the click with a close div. But it returns 500 error.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).on('click','figure', function(){
      var pk = $(this).data('id');
      $('#main').load("/gallery/"+ pk +" #content", function() {
        $('.close').click(function(){
          $('#content').load("/gallery/"+" #main", function() {
            /// can add another function here
          });
        });

      });
    });

</script>
```

And the local body looks like

```
{% block body %}
<div id="main">
<section class="gallerySection">
<div class="gallery">
  {% for obj in object_list %}
  <figure data-id="{{obj.pk}}">
    <img src="{{obj.photo.url}}" />

    <figcaption>
      <div class="additional">
        <p id="caption">{{obj.caption}}</p>
      </div>
      <p id="credit">{{obj.credit}}</p>
    </figcaption>


  </figure>
  {% endfor %}


</div>
</section>
</div>

{% endblock body %}
```

now in the /gallery/pk I am taking #content is like

```
{% block body %}
<div id="content">
<div class="close" data-id="{{object.id}}">
  <img id="close" src="{% static '/images/close.png' %}" />
  </div>
<section class="detailSection">

  <div class="imagewrap">
    <img src="{{object.photo.url}}" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <h1>{{object.caption}}</h1>
    <p>{{object.description}}</p>
    <span>{{object.credit}}</span>
  </div>

  <p id="credit">{{obj.credit}}</p>
  </section>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

The error:
[The server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycAfF.png)

This says the template name is gallery_list.page.html but it doesnt actually exist.

Views.py

```
class GalleryView(AjaxListView):
    context_object_name = "object_list"
    template_name = "gallery.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gallery.objects.all()


class GalleryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Gallery
    template_name = "gallery_details.html"
```

[Where my browser says is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX8Sc.png)

Comment: A 500 error means the error is in your server side Django logic. If you check the error you can see it's because 'TemplateDoesNotExist: website/gallery_list_page.html'. Check the path and try again.

Comment: Looks like it's in the `data-id` on one of your `figure` elements

Comment: It works upto here so the data-id might not be the problem. 
      $('#main').load("/gallery/"+ pk +" #content", function() {

Comment: It is, because the problem is the value in `pk`, which is the `data-id` of the `figure` which was clicked...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can I solve it? SORRY I'm A NOOB

Comment: I don't know as you've not shown enough information. All I can tell you is that the problem is with that data attribute. You need to investigate what the value currently is, and what it should be, as something is not right.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please elaborate on it a bit more..

Comment: I'm not sure what more there is to say. You use the value to create a URL, and the URL doesn't exist. That's it.

Comment: The url that I had created using the value works right but in the next line it uses the div inside the foreign element that we loaded from the upper url.  Can we not do that?